# Filters Dropdown Menu

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm a newbie when it comes to Google Maps and all the technologies around it and I'm trying to learn a thing at a time.

I have managed to create my Google map from [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) where I populate database with information on alumni of my university department and I want to have filters whereby when one selects say a year, it will show only alumni that graduated on a given year, or say only females or males,also filter by courses.

I'm trying to create something like a visualization tool for showing distribution of alumni across the united states based on the criteria.

In my database I store name, addresses, automatically geocode the addresses and store lat and lng, majors, year of graduation to name a few. I can't think of a way to have the drop down or say checkboxes for filtering the markers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to use gmap, you have to do a heavy javascript. I have done it this way:
When I render the page(php), I populate the javascript array with the values.
Then, I add listener to the drop-down. When value is changed, I evaluate selected value versus my JS array and then I send the coordinates from my array to google maps-show marker function; in addition, I have a hashmap where I store my markers (the one which are being shown on the map), so when I change the drop-down, I go over my hashmap and remove my markers from the map. 
I am hoping this makes sense. In addition, I would suggest that you start using the json to populate your arrays dynamicly each time you need to acquire data from the DB.
I would suggest that you ask shorter questions and provide some code we could tickle it.

Comment: I have the map I'm working on here http://daressalaam.co.tz/project2/ please view source to see what I currently have.I'll try to learn and tweak the code to see if I'll manage to do what you have advised.Let me know if you have a different opinion after taking a viewing the code.

Comment: can you take a look at my map daressalaam.co.tz/project2 and advise on how to actually implement,I'm stuck